# deploying cloud-sql-proxy with args and instance id as Cloud Run sidecar

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am trying to deploy the Cloud SQL proxy as a Cloud Run sidecar, and cnanot get args to work correctly

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['beta', 'run', 'deploy', "${_SERVICE_NAME}", 
  '--region', 'europe-west1', 
  '--platform', 'managed', 
  '--allow-unauthenticated',
  '--execution-environment','gen1',
  '--container','nginx','--image', "${_IMAGE_NAME}-nginx", '--port','8080','--memory','128Mi', 
  '--container','clousql-proxy','--image', "gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:latest",'--memory','128Mi', '--args',"--instances=shop:europe-west1:shophost-db=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 --port=5432"
```

for some unknown reason the `args` section doesn't like the params given
How do I add the `instance name` and `port`?

Comment: 1) Delete the service between test runs. 2) `--port` can be specified once. 3) `--args` is a comma-separated list. Are you trying to pass `--port=5432` to `--args` or to `--container`? 4) The Cloud SQL Proxy uses a single hyphen for flags, you used two hyphens 5) Try `--command=/cloud_sql_proxy` and `--args="-instances=shop:europe-west1:shophost-db=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432"` and delete the second `--port` flag.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to CloudSQL from cloud run with the auth proxy, you just need to specify the `--add-cloudsql-instances` flag instead of doing the sidecar. When you provide that flag with the cloud sql connection string like `PROJECT-ID:REGION:INSTANCE-ID` then it will create the auth proxy side car for you.

Check out [this page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-run) which has the documentation you need.